# Update field in DE using Rows.Update with multiple search keys

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, sfmc-business-unit

I'm trying to update a field in my DE. And I want to search Row with multiple keys in method with this code:

```
function setRegisreField(dataExtensionKey, firstKeyValue, secondKeyValue) {
        var data = {
            updatedData: {
                Registered: 'True'
            }
        };


        var updatedData = data.updatedData;

        try {
            var sourceData = retrieveDataExtension(dataExtensionKey);
            sourceData.Rows.Update(updatedData, ['firstKey', 'secondKey'], [firstKeyValue, secondKeyValue]);
        }
        catch (error) {
            Write(Stringify(error));
        }
    }
```

But i have an arror: "message":"Object expected: Update","jintException" ...

Is there an option to use several keys in the Rows.Update to find the unique row and updte the field?

Answer (score 0):

The key names / key values are in an array to be listed, so defining multiples should work. Also the documentation talks about columnS and valueS here.
Not saying the documentation is great, but sure it's a starting point.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsUpdate.htm

So is the error message: "object expected" tells you there is something wrong with the objects in your code. - not the arrays (  `['firstKey', 'secondKey']` and `[firstKeyValue, secondKeyValue]` ), those are fine.

Can you verify:

1. For testing this, try  and isolate the error by just writing the object into your update line to get less moving parts:

```
sourceData.Rows.Update({Registered:'true'}, ['firstKey', 'secondKey'], [firstKeyValue, secondKeyValue]);
```

If that doesn't work, then the "object expected" would be the missing data extension (sourceData), not the {Registered:'true'} object.

2. sourceData should be your data extension, initialised by name:.

```
var deName = "myDE";
var sourceData = DataExtension.Init(deName);
```

Currently you are trying "retrieveDataExtension(dataExtensionKey)" - is that function defined somewhere else in your code? If not, replace it with init as above.

Also you should be just able to set the following instead of lines 2-9:

```
var updatedData = { Registered: 'True'}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It works!

Comment: nice, please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem :)